# Tensorboard doesn't show scalars anymore

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I decided to update tensorboard because it wasn't showing the graph,
on the graph panel all I could see was a blank page with no error message.
Now that I have updated the graph, is the only thing my tensorboard shows. Now I cannot see scalars or histograms. I have the:

```
No scalar data was found.
```

message, and the same for histograms etc.

This is the relevant parts of my code:

```
def train_model(self):

    with tf.Session(graph=self.graph) as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())#Now all variables should be initialized.
        print("Uninitialized variables: ", session.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables())) #Just to check, should print nothing

        self.train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.default_folder+"/logs/train", graph=session.graph)
        self.test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.default_folder+"/logs/test", graph=session.graph)

        print("Training for ", self.n_steps)
        for step in range(self.n_steps):

            feed_train = self._create_feed_dict(self.X_train,step)
            feed_test = self._create_feed_dict(self.X_test,step)

            session.run(self.optimizer, feed_dict = {self.v_clamp: feed_train})

            #Get the loss in tensorborad
            loss_train = session.run(self.summary_loss, feed_dict = {self.v_clamp: feed_train})
            self.train_writer.add_summary(loss_train, step)
            self.train_writer.flush()
            loss_test = session.run(self.summary_loss, feed_dict = {self.v_clamp: feed_test})
            self.test_writer.add_summary(loss_test, step)
            self.test_writer.flush()

            if (step%1000)==0:
                histograms = session.run(self.merged, feed_dict = {self.v_clamp: feed_train})
                self.train_writer.add_summary(histograms, step)
                self.train.flush()
                self.saver.save(session, self.default_folder + self.model_name, global_step = step)
                print(step)
```

I created these variables inside my build_model method.

```
def _build_model():
...
        with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer_1"):
            self.W = tf.get_variable(name = "w", dtype = tf.float32, shape=[self.n_visibles, self.n_hidden], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=0.01,minval=-0.01))
            hist1=tf.summary.histogram("hidden_layer_1" + '/weights', self.W)

            self.bh = tf.get_variable(name = "b_h", dtype = tf.float32, shape=[self.n_hidden], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=0.01,minval=-0.01))
            hist2=tf.summary.histogram("hidden_layer_1" + '/biases', self.bh)

            if self.hidden_activation == 'sigma':
                self.h_clamp = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.v_clamp,self.W) + self.bh)
            elif self.hidden_activation == 'relu':
                self.h_clamp = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.v_clamp,self.W) + self.bh)
            elif self.hidden_activation == 'tanh':
                self.h_clamp = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(self.v_clamp,self.W) + self.bh)  
            hist3=tf.summary.histogram("hidden_layer_1" + '/h', self.h_clamp)
...
       #Get loss in tensorboard       
        with tf.variable_scope("compute_loss"):
            self.loss_function = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_clamp - v_free)))
            self.summary_loss = tf.summary.scalar("loss", self.loss_function) #this is what we need to run!
        self.merged = tf.summary.merge([hist1,hist2,hist3])

        #Object to save variable weights and more
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

My default_folder is "./models/GSSU-RBM/". and my model_name is "myRBM".

I execute tensorboard like this:

```
tensorboard --logdir "C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM"
```

And I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread Reloader:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 361, in _reload_forever
    reload_multiplexer(multiplexer, path_to_run)
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 335, in reload_multiplexer
    multiplexer.Reload()
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_multiplexer.py", line 195, in Reload
    accumulator.Reload()
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_accumulator.py", line 186, in Reload
    self._ProcessEvent(event)
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\event_processing\plugin_event_accumulator.py", line 332, in _ProcessEvent
    value = data_compat.migrate_value(value)
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\data_compat.py", line 57, in migrate_value
    return handler(value) if handler else value
  File "c:\users\isaac\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\data_compat.py", line 106, in _migrate_scalar_value
    tensor_proto = tf.make_tensor_proto(scalar_value)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'make_tensor_proto'
```

BTW I'm running this with tensorflow-gpu on Windows 10, on a jupyter notebook on anaconda. I installed tensorboard like `pip install tensorboard` and tensorflow-gpu through conda.

EDIT: Also, the edit from my --inspect
Doing: `tensorboard --inspect --logdir "C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM"`
I get:

```
These tags are in C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM\logs\test:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   compute_loss/loss
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM\logs\test:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            84487
   max_step             84487
   min_step             0
   num_steps            84488
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================

These tags are in C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM\logs\train:
audio -
histograms
   hidden_layer_1/hidden_layer_1/biases
   hidden_layer_1/hidden_layer_1/h
   hidden_layer_1/hidden_layer_1/weights
images -
scalars
   compute_loss/loss
tensor -
======================================================================

Event statistics for C:\Users\isaac\Desktop\TFM\models\GSSU-RBM\logs\train:
audio -
graph
   first_step           0
   last_step            0
   max_step             0
   min_step             0
   num_steps            1
   outoforder_steps     []
histograms
   first_step           0
   last_step            84000
   max_step             84000
   min_step             0
   num_steps            85
   outoforder_steps     []
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            84599
   max_step             84599
   min_step             0
   num_steps            84600
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
tensor -
======================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! In case someone is in the same situation, the solution was to uninstall conda tensorflow and install it through pip. 
It gaves you later an error requesting for an specific cuda and cudnn. 
Once you install these two it should work.